# How to save and retrieve Azure spatial anchor App-Properties from azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, spatial, azure-spatial-anchors

Hi i want to save and retrieve some extra data in spatial anchor cosmos-db. currently app save only anchor key but i want to save some extra data like note URL and marker color with spatial anchor.i found a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-unity which have code to save app properties with cloud anchor but still I am unable to save these app properties to cosmos-db database and also unable to retrieve.sorry for my bad English and please help if anyone have solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.cloudspatialanchor.appproperties#Microsoft_Azure_SpatialAnchors_CloudSpatialAnchor_AppProperties), and see if tweaking with the app properties might help you. You can also have a look at this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors) to see how we are using Azure Cosmos DB with ASA samples. If you are still facing problems, having a look at Azure Cosmos DB documentation might be the best next step. And you can always share more details about the exact problem here to get more help :)